# How can I run new independent process from node.js process

Tags: node.js, process, fork

Is there any way, how to run a new independent process from node.js process?

Example:

```
console.log('Starting new process')
// fork bash script.sh
process.exit()
```

Node.js process is dead and script.sh still running.

I don't know how to implement, which function should I use?